# How to make the flock works properly in lua

Tags: linux, lua, flock

I am trying to make file lock in order to synchronize parallel access to a file by many process lua

here after my lua source code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local M = require 'posix.fcntl'


local S = require 'posix.sys.stat'


function sleep(n)
  os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(n))
end

local fd = M.open(
   'file.txt',
   M.O_CREAT + M.O_WRONLY + M.O_TRUNC,
   S.S_IRUSR + S.S_IWUSR + S.S_IRGRP + S.S_IROTH
)

-- Set lock on file
local lock = {
   l_type = M.F_WRLCK;     -- Exclusive lock
   l_whence = M.SEEK_SET;  -- Relative to beginning of file
   l_start = 0;            -- Start from 1st byte
   l_len = 0;              -- Lock whole file
}

print("lock lua\n");
if M.fcntl(fd, M.F_SETLK, lock) == -1 then
   print("file locked by another process")
end

print("sleep 30 lua\n");
sleep(30)
print("end sleep lua\n");

-- Do something with file while it's locked
--require 'posix.unistd'.write(fd, 'Lorem ipsum\n')


-- Release the lock
lock.l_type = M.F_UNLCK
M.fcntl(fd, M.F_SETLK, lock)
print("loock released lua\n");
```

when I run this lua script twice at the same time the flock return success immediately for both run. I expected that the first launch will take the lock of the file and I expected that the second run will be blocked in the lock call till the first run release the lock

what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in this check:

```
if M.fcntl(fd, M.F_SETLK, lock) == -1 then
```

should be

```
if M.fcntl(fd, M.F_SETLK, lock) == nil then
```